# How to programmatically prevent closing OpenOffice from the menu File / Close?

Tags: java, openoffice.org

I've created a java code to load OpenOffice document and want to prevent the user to close the document from the menu file / close.

According to the document, it seems CloseVetoException would do the job.  However, as I test the code, it seems not working at all.

```
XCloseable xCloseable = (XCloseable)UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XCloseable.class, xTextDocument); 
//xTextDocument is an instance of com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument
xCloseable.addCloseListener(new XCloseListener() {

    @Override
    public void disposing(EventObject event) {
        System.out.println("firing XCloseListener.disposing " + event.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void queryClosing(EventObject event, boolean arg1)
            throws CloseVetoException {
        System.out.println("firing MyCloseListener.queryClosing " + event.toString());
        throw new CloseVetoException();
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyClosing(EventObject event) {
        System.out.println("firing MyCloseListener.notifyClosing " + event.toString());
    }
});
```

While I'm trying to close the document from menu file / close, it seems the document window has been closed also, but notifyClosing and disposing did not fired.

Comment: I am not sure it is a good idea.... Users may want to close documents for legitimate reasons.

Comment: Preventing users from doing something that they're accustomed to being able to do is pretty much always bad for UX. Unless you have an *extremely good* reason for preventing them from closing the documents, don't try to. (Note: 'because I don't want them to' does not constitute a good reason).

Comment: I've planned to add variety of additional dialog and user interface.  And also control how and where the document should be saved, so I think control OpenOffice UI would be the best solution for my situation.

However, I'm currently looking into plugin solution and embedded Open Office into my custom frame also.